# Find the argument

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, problem-solving

Find the argument

> $$\begin{align}
> &A. \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}2+\frac i2 \right)^7 \\  
> &B. (11 − i 11\sqrt{3})^9
> \end{align}$$

I get $\frac{7\pi}6 +2kπ$ for A. I just want to make sure that I am doing this right. I also believe that argument and Argument are two different concepts. In this case argument is being used.

Comment: Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: If you are sure that your result is correct, you do not need to ask. If you suspect the possibility of an error, you need to provide some more steps of your solution process so that one can pinpoint the error. So A looks right, what are your insights to B?